# Class 'Bar' used before its declaration

Tags: javascript, function, class, typescript, constants

I have a class named `Bar`:

```
class Bar {
  private readonly foo: string;
  constructor() {
    this.foo = "foo";
  }
}
```

And in my main file I'm trying to use it like this:

```
const bar: Bar = new Bar();
```

But this line gives me the error:

> Class 'Bar' used before its declaration.

I can make it a `var` and declare it inside a function but I'm looking for a better solution which allows me to declare the `bar` as a constant.

The problem is Typescript compiling the project into a single Javascript file which declares the class after the attempted use.

Altough [@Fenton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48189989/8593176) works fine. There is another:

Inside `tsconfig.json` you can type:

```
"files": [
    "libs/Bar.ts",
],
"include": [
    "**/*"
]
```

This will tell Typescript to compile `libs/Bar.ts` before the others.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: How is the first snippet related to the second one exactly?

Comment: Where do you `export`/ `import` ?

Comment: @deceze The first snippet is a class inside the file "./libs/Bar.ts" and the constant I showed in the second snippet is from the file "./Main.ts" that gives me the error.

Comment: @JonasW. I don't use export or import because the output is a single file targeting es5.

Comment: And in that single file, the class declaration comes before the attempted use, yes…?

Comment: No, Typescript putting the class declaration after the attempted use which probably causing the error that I can't resolve.

Comment: Right, so how exactly do you get from two to one file without using export or import?

Comment: The Typescript compiling to one single Javascript file.

Comment: @menfie the "output" does not matter. Typescript will transpile / bundle it...

Comment: @JonasW. It does not allow me to use export without changing the module to `amd` or `system` and I can't do that. The best I can do is the `tsconfig` trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to hint to the compiler that the other file is there, although this depends on your IDE as some work this out for themselves.

```
///<reference path="./libs/Bar.ts" />

const bar: Bar = new Bar();
```

## Notes on Comments

> This is so ugly... - Jonas W.

My opinion has long been that you should [prefer modules, and module loaders over namespaces, and reference comments](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/stop-mixing-typescript-modules-and-namespaces/). It has been my opinion since [before they were called this](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/), but bear in mind the OP has already made this comment.

> I don't use export or import because the output is a single file targeting es5

Now it *is* in fact still possible to achieve a single file output, targeting ES5, even if you write modules with imports, because you can use additional tooling to process the modules into a single file, or you can use a module loader like SystemJS or RequireJS - but we ought to consider how much subjectivity we ought to introduce to an answer; and how appropriate it may be to attempt to convert every person with a question to our own workflow.

For example, [I disagree with bundling an entire program into a single script](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/10/continuous-delivery-javascript-bundling/) file*, when it could be better delivered by leaving the modules intact - but I don't try to answer every webpack question with that.

* I disagree to the extent that bundling is currently heralded as being a "best practice", based on dated premises.

Comment: This is so ugly. If typescript supports `import` & `export` one should use it!

Comment: @JonasW. TypeScript supports reference comments too, so I can re-use your argument to say we should all use reference comments (disclaimer: this is a critical thinking jest, so please don't take offense). I've expanded in the answer - philosophically, I'm not sure how much an answer to a small specific question should attempt to change someone's TypeScript workflow. Perhaps there's a meta for this?